# KeyError, Exception Value: 'object'

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

[image: Projects picture]1

I'm working on Django. I'm getting the error below. I didn't find the solution despite the much increased.[Please refer the this link for trace back](http://dpaste.com/1ZN7VKP)

### Codes in views.py

```
class UpdateVote(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    form_class = VoteForm
    queryset = Vote.objects.all()

    def get_object(self,queryset=None):
        vote = super().get_object(queryset)
        user = self.request.user
        if vote.user != user:
            raise PermissionDenied('can not change another user vote')
        return vote
    def get_success_url(self):
        movie_id = self.object.movie.id
        return reverse('core:movie_detail', kwargs={'pk':movie_id})
    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        movie_id = context['object'].id
        movie_detail_url = reverse('core:movie_detail',kwargs={'pk':movie_id})
        return redirect(to=movie_detail_url)

class MovieDetail(DetailView):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all_with_prefetch_persons()
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            vote = Vote.objects.get_vote_or_unsaved_blank_vote(movie=self.object,user=self.request.user)
            if vote.id:
                vote_url_form = reverse('core:UpdateVote',kwargs={'movie_id':vote.movie.id,'pk':vote.id})
            else:
                vote_url_form = (reverse('core:create_vote',kwargs={'movie_id':self.object.id}))
            vote_form = VoteForm(instance=vote)
            ctx['vote_form'] = vote_form
            ctx['vote_url_form'] = vote_url_form
        return ctx
```

### Codes in form.py

I have used this form to link with UpdateView

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .models import Movie,Vote
class VoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.HiddenInput,queryset=get_user_model().objects.all(),disabled=True)
    movie = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.HiddenInput,queryset = Movie.objects.all(),disabled=True)
    value = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect,choices=Vote.VALUE_CHOICE)
    class Meta:
        model = Vote
        fields = ('value','user','movie',)
```

### urls.py

This is the url mapping for the view.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .views import MovieList,MovieDetail,PersonDetail,CreateVote,UpdateVote
app_name = 'core'
urlpatterns = [
    path('movies/', MovieList.as_view(), name='movie_list'),
    path('movie/<int:pk>/', MovieDetail.as_view(), name='movie_details'),
    path('person/<int:pk>/', PersonDetail.as_view(), name='person_details'),
    path('movie/<int:movie_id>/vote/', CreateVote.as_view(), name='create_vote'),
    path('movie/<int:movie_id>/vote/<int:pk>', UpdateVote.as_view(), name='UpdateVote'),
]
```

### HTML template

This is the template I used.

```
{% block sidebar %}
    <div>
    {% if vote_form %}
        <form action="{{vote_form_url}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ vote_form.as_p }}
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" >Vote</button>
        </form>
    {%  else %}
        <p>Login to vote for this movie</p>
    {% endif %} </div> {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hi Sanjay, it's me again. Please provide the traceback so that we can trace where the error comes from

Comment: hey @ToanQuocHo  :) I just pasted link for the traceback please look at it.

Comment: UpdateVote's object is not a Movie object so that you can't get the movie id via object like that (`context['object'].id`). In the urls, you've already added `movie_id` (`'movie/<int:movie_id>/vote/<int:pk>'`) so in here you can get it by `movie_id = self.kwargs.get('movie_id')`

Comment: Toan it's working but voted value is not appearing even after I voted. It's again comes with fresh page. I will add the screenshot for that please look at it if it is possible and suggest above comment as answer.

Comment: @ToanQuocHo Can you suggest me how to become master in django? Please suggest if there is any content, book or tutorial on django to be profitient.

Comment: If you want to become master on something, just practice more and more. Find any tutorial, source code which has something to do with Django and read it. You also can take a look at Django testing framework, which helped me a lot to understand Django stuff at the beginning. Just keep practicing and reading a lot, try to implementing a complete Django project and understand as most as possible the code inside the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UpdateVote` view is using `VoteForm` and the queryset on that view is from `Vote` model, so that the `object` field inside that view is the instance of `Vote` model, not `Movie` model.

This code `movie_id = context['object'].id` also not work because context might not included `object` of `UpdateVote` view, that caused the error `KeyError, Exception Value: 'object'`. You could get `movie_id` via `kwargs` field inside `UpdateVote` view because you've already defined `movie_id` in the path.

With this:

```py
path('movie/<int:movie_id>/vote/<int:pk>', UpdateVote.as_view(), name='UpdateVote'),
```

Your view can get the values by using `kwargs` like so:

```py
class UpdateVote(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    form_class = VoteForm
    queryset = Vote.objects.all()

    def get_object(self,queryset=None):
        vote = super().get_object(queryset)
        user = self.request.user
        if vote.user != user:
            raise PermissionDenied('can not change another user vote')
        return vote

    def get_success_url(self):
        movie_id = self.kwargs.get('movie_id')
        return reverse('core:movie_detail', kwargs={'pk':movie_id})

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        movie_id = self.kwargs.get('movie_id')
        movie_detail_url = reverse('core:movie_detail',kwargs={'pk':movie_id})
        return redirect(to=movie_detail_url)
```

Comment: @Sanjay, it suppose to be update after you clicked the button. Is there any delaying operation inside `get_vote_or_unsaved_blank_vote` method? and btw, the UI in the screenshot looks different than your template code above.